# propel not working in windows

Tags: php, windows, propel

I was testing using Propel for web application development, but bumping into some obstacles in the very installation of Propel.

As exposed in their documentation (http://propelorm.org/documentation/01-installation.html), I don't think any method other than [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) will work in sucessfully installing Propel. I tried with Github, but the result was an error when checking the validity of the installation: **Could not open input file: propel**

So I focused on Composer, and the same error when following Propel documentation commands `$ php composer.phar install` **Could not open input file: composer.phar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out that their documentation don't expose the correct syntax to run **Composer** with Windows CMD. Also Composer documentation doesn't expose that, neither (or I just couldn't find that).

So I deleted previous propel files, and tried just `composer install`, with composer.json file set up, of course.

And it worked fine!

Hopes this helps someone struggling with this.